# Where are packages being installed?

Tags: python, pip, package, anaconda

I have uninstalled and re-installed Anaconda on drive `D:` because drive `C:` is out of storage. I thought that the newly installed packages would be installed on drive `D:`, but when I use pip install XXX, it still take up space on drive `C:`. (I have already activated the virtual environment.)

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

`conda info -e` - tells you which python env is being used

`conda install python=3.11.2` - installs a new python

`conda install -n <venvname> -p <path to where I like to put my venv> python=3.11.2` - install a python to a given directory

`conda activate <venvname>` - activates it

I prefer using pyenv|poetry|pipenv|venv and requirements.txt pip management, it is much clearer and not dependent upon anaconda versions. so this may have changed in recent versions :-)